# filetype plugin not loaded on files opened with edit command

Tags: buffers, indentation, filetype

I've turned on filetype indent and plugins on with the following in my vimrc file:

> filetype indent plugin on

Everything is fine when I open a file from terminal, but if I open another buffer through the :edit command, it doesn't seem to load the any of the indent settings (doesn't expand tabs, different shiftwidth, etc). The first buffer has all the correct settings. All subsequent files opened with edit do not.
Any idea why and how I might fix this?

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in your vimrc. You can try an auto command as well.